# How to use a Spring profile expression?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot: **2.0.4.RELEASE**

I have specified a Spring Boot [multi-profile YAML](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-multi-profile-yaml) configuration file:

```
server:
        address: 192.168.1.100
---
spring:
        profiles: development
server:
        address: 127.0.0.1
---
spring:
        profiles: production | eu-central
server:
        address: 192.168.1.120
```

According to the [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-definition-profiles-java), if the `production` **or** `eu-central` profile is active, the `server.address` property is `192.168.1.120`. But when I run this test

```java
@ActiveProfiles({"production"})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ProfileTest {

  @Autowired
  private Environment environment;
  @Value("${server.address}")
  private String serverAddress;

  @Test
  public void testProfile() {
    assertThat(environment.getActiveProfiles(), is(new String[] {"production"} ));
    assertThat(serverAddress, is("192.168.1.120"));
  }

}
```

it fails:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 

Expected: is "192.168.1.120"
     but: was "192.168.1.100"
        at com.example.demo.ProfileTest.testProfile(ProfileTest.java:27)
```

Why does the test fail and how do I use a Spring profile expression correctly?
By the way, if I remove  `| eu-central` from the `spring.profiles` key the test passes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boris. I've studied your problem. And I think that I've found a bug in Spring-boot. I've reported an issue so you can check it. The problem is SpringBoot always use default value for ${server.address} because framework couldn't recognise profiles: production | eu-central as a List of profiles. If I use

```
@ActiveProfiles(value = "production | eu-central")
```

All is ok.

The link on Spring-boot issue here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14314

So, you could see the discussion. 
Thank you!

**UPDATED**

I've got an answer from Spring Team on my Issue.

> This format is a Spring Framework 5.1 (and therefore a Spring Boot 2.1
>   feature).

So the answer on your question is 
**This feature will be available in Spring Boot 2.1.**

Comment: So, I've got an answer from Spring team in my ticket. This format is a Spring Framework 5.1 (and therefore a Spring Boot 2.1 feature).  I think now your question has  an answer, we need to wait Spring Boot 2.1

Comment: Thanks @petrobruin, I used a Spring Boot version 2.0.4.RELEASE, but current-SNAPSHOT version of the reference docs. My bad.